# How to show only disqus thread-votes and nothing else

Tags: css, javascript, iframe

I want to show just the thread vote portion of the whole Disqus commenting system. How would I go about doing it? Here is an example of what I am asking for:

[image: Screenshot of what I want]

Could I possibly iframed the rating element and display it only?

Answer (score 1):

Can you identify HTML elements using some developer tools?

If so, the simplest solution is to add `display: none;` CSS style to every element in the Disqus iframe except on the `div` containing thread votes.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked out a website with Disqus and I think I got it right. Try this:

```
#conversation,#post-count,#discovery,#profile,#dashboard,#community,#main-nav {
display: none!important;
}
```